# Take action based on values of Radiobutton and checkbox on button click in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Need to generate a single plot based values selected from Radio-button and Checkbox.

- Radio button 1(RB1): Temperature, Humidity, Pressure.
- Radio button 2(RB2): For 24 Hrs, 48Hrs.
- Checkbox(CB1): India, England, Italy.

I should be able to select from RB1, RB2, CB3(Temperature, 24Hrs, India respectively) and based on values of these, need to generate corresponding plot as output.
An illustration in Bokeh, Python for similar example would be of great help.

I am able to react or take action based on only one input of either RB1 or RB2 or CB1 at a time. Could not take action based on all the values at the same time.

Comment: To help others help you, pleas share actual code of what you have tried, that is not working.

Comment: Am not able to code this as this functionality does not seem to exist.

Comment: Well, for example here is an example that uses the values of four separate sliders "at the same time" https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py It really depends on what you mean by "at the same time" which is why seeing what code you have tried already is helpful to understand what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell, you want this pattern:

```
# Set up multiple widgets
offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
amplitude = Slider(title="amplitude", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
phase = Slider(title="phase", value=0.0, start=0.0, end=2*np.pi)
freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1, step=0.1)

# Set up one callback for all the widgets, that uses all their values
def update_data(attrname, old, new):

    # Get all the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    b = offset.value
    w = phase.value
    k = freq.value

    # Generate the new curve based on all the values
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
    y = a*np.sin(k*x + w) + b

    # This update uses values from all four sliders at the same time
    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)
```

Here I have illustrated with `Slider` but the principle holds for any widgets.